# Angular MdSelect no underline not defined

Tags: css, angular, material-design, angular-material2

I am working with [Material for Angular](https://material.angular.io/). I need to define a [md-select component](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) within a custom component. The fact is that I need the md-select to have no underline similar to the [solution](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9105) for AngularJS.

According to the generated elements, I am trying to define the CSS classes as follow, but they are not working.

my.component.html

```
<span>My Component</span>
<md-select placeholder="My Select" floatPlaceholder="never">
    <md-option *ngFor="let option of options" 
[value]="option.value">{{option.viewValue}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

my.component.scss

```
.mat-select { /* This is working */
    display: block;
    width: 396px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: $pale-gray-two;
    padding: 11px 13px 14px !important;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    color: $greyish-brown-two !important;

}

.mat-select-trigger { /* This is not working */ 

    .mat-select-underline {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do something like this, because of CSS specificity

my.component.html

```
<span>My Component</span>
<md-select placeholder="My Select" floatPlaceholder="never" class="no-underline">
    <md-option *ngFor="let option of options" 
    [value]="option.value">{{option.viewValue}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

my.component.scss

```
.no-underline {

    .mat-select-underline {
        display: none !important;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/deep/ .mat-select-underline {
    display: none;
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/B4HmhT?p=preview)